# How can I make magento product sidebar sticky when I scroll?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, magento

I am making a online store in Magento. I want to make its default sidebar to custom sticky sidebar when I scroll.

Links:

- http://tara.psweb.in/
- http://tara.psweb.in/index.php/bags.html

Comment: Can you include some of your existing code?

Comment: http://tara.psweb.in/index.php/sale.html                                                                              See left side bar is scrollable.                                                                                     I want to make it sticky

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this...

```
var thisScroll = 0, lastScroll = 0;
var cutoff = 145 (whatever the threshold for the switch should be)
$(window).scroll(function(){
 if(thisScroll > lastScroll && thisScroll > cutoff {
   $(navbar).addClass('fixed');
 }
 else if (lastScroll > thisScroll && lastScroll < cutoff{
  $(navbar).removeClass('fixed');
 }
});
```

Then you can just use CSS to do the sticky side-nav (just add position:fixed and anything else you wanna shift for the transition)

Comment: I want to make custom phtml template code to do the same.

Comment: You can use CSS and not use JavaScript if you don't mind the sidebar being fixed all the time instead of sticking once you scroll down like the nav bar. If you need to keep in in a phtml template you can just add an inline style block to your sidebar, position:fixed and probably give it some distance from the top to compensate for it being locked.

Comment: by doing position fixed it is overlapping footer.

Comment: You'll want the footer's width to be something like width: calc(100% - sidebarwidth) then float it to the right - that way there will be space next to the footer for the sidebar to sit.